# What else (other than Star Wars) has Lucas retconned?

Tags: george-lucas

We know Lucas has a habit of making a movie, then changing it every time he re-releases it.  (If you're not clear what I'm looking for, Google "Han Shot First.")

Does he do this with only Star Wars movies, or does he do it with other properties?  Has he retconned *American Graffiti* or any other movies he's directed?  And has he managed to do anything like that with the Indiana Jones movies, which he created the stories and characters for, but which Spielberg directed?

Just how far into other movies has his habit to retcon reached?

Comment: The wall shot first (I didn't watch American Graffiti but I assume a wall must have been in it for the graffity to be placed on),

Comment: @DVK: No.  It's "Han shot."  Not first, since Greedo never shot at all, so Han didn't shoot first.  He shot and that was the end of it.

Comment: I don't suppose the edits for DVD release count. He removed the "Playduck" magazine from Howard The Duck.

Comment: @GorchestopherH: I think that'd count.  I'm trying to find out if he does this whenever he can, or if it's only SW.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In 2004, Lucas released his Director's Cut of [THX 1138](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/THX_1138). There are no changes as big as making Greedo shooting at Han, but the there were still some controversial changes. Here a quote from [The O.C. Wikia *George Lucas* article, *Controversy* section](http://oc.wikia.com/wiki/George_Lucas#Controversy).

> Changes Lucas personally made to THX 1138 for its 2004 DVD release further re-enforced criticism from fans who felt that he was spoiling the integrity of his original films.

As an example, a significant change he made with THX that he didn't do to Star Wars was reordering some scenes. You could see a exhaustive list of changes [here](http://www.maverick-media.co.uk/movies/thx_1138_1971/changes_001.html) and [here](http://www.movie-censorship.com/report.php?ID=541751). Here is the whole Postscript section of the first link (Emphasis mine):

> **Although the story stays pretty much the same the movie has been extensively changed. I'm sure George Lucas would claim that he couldn't accomplish his original vision back in 1970 due to the technology of the time and budget**, so changes and additions could be seen as reasonable. The thing is though, George Lucas doesn't mention on the DVD that there has been any changes made at all, in the interviews, commentary, packaging, anywhere, the only mention is that the movie has been restored, this all seems very strange indeed...
>
> As you can see George Lucas and ILM have done a wonderful job (except for the ones I have mentioned) in updating and widening the scope of THX's world for the masses to enjoy. This is a testament to the original movie that it can still be viewed today without looking too 70s. **Some people may not like the changes, preferring instead the original, however, in my opinion they are both excellent.** The George Lucas Director's Cut should have been released with the restored original theatrical cut rather than the way it has been released.

Comment: I think re-doing all the special effects, and then re-cutting the entire movie is far bigger than making Greedo shoot first!

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Are you saying that making Greedo shoot first is a smaller change than something else? ***Heresy!***

Comment: Haha! I see what you're saying.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt You're both right. The scope of overhauling is larger than making Greedo shoot, but the impact is not as significant because it didn't change the 'facts' of the story.

Comment: @BrienMalone Actually there are many minor changes to the story: http://thunderpeel2001.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/george-lucass-thx-1138-explored-part-1.html

Comment: Apologies, @DavRob60.  I thought I had picked an answer and lost track of this.  Sorry it took a few years...